# Probability Counterfeit and Genuine coins

Tags: probability

Please check if my answers to this probability problem are correct. I would highly appreciate your help/assistance.  Thanks

> A team was formed to investigate the proliferation of counterfeit
>   coins. It was found that the weight of genuine coins is normally
>   distributed with µ = 27 grams and standard deviation= 4 grams, and the
>   weight of counterfeit coins is normally distributed with µ = 23 grams
>   and standard deviation  5 grams. It was also estimated that 80% of
>   coins in circulation are genuine, and the rest are counterfeit.

**A**. What is the probability that a cashier gives you a counterfeit coin that weighs more than 25 grams?

$P(G) = 0.80$ genuine coins in the circulation

$P(C) = 0.20$ counterfeit coins in the circulation

$P(C ≥ 25) =   ( 25-23)÷ 5      =    2/5$  or $0.40$

$ =  1 – P(z ≤ 0.4)   =  1 – 0.6554$

$=  0.3446$

$P(C ≥ 25) = (0.3446) x (0.20) = 0.0689$ or $6.89\%$ - probability  that a cashier gives you a counterfeit coin that weighs more than 25 grams.

---

**B**.  What is the probability that a randomly chosen genuine coin weighs more than 25 grams?

$P(G ≥ 25) =    (25-27)÷4      =    - 2/4$  or  $-0.50$

$  =   P(z ≤ 0.50)   =  0.6915$

$P(G ≥ 25) = (0.6915) \cdot (0.80) = 0.5532$ or $55.32\%$ - probability  that a randomly chosen genuine coin weighs more than 25 grams.

---

**C**.  What is the probability that the cashier will give you a coin that weighs more than 25 grams and is a counterfeit?

$P(≥25 \cap C) = P(G ≥ 25) \cdot  P(C ≥ 25) 
          =   0.5532 \cdot  0.0689$

$= 0.0381$ or $3.81\%$   - probability that a cashier will give you a coin that weighs more than 25 grams and is a counterfeit

---

**D**.  What is the probability that the coin from the cashier that weighs more than 25 grams is counterfeit?

$P(≥25|C)  =   P(≥25 \cap  C)÷P(C)$

$=  0.0381÷0.20   =   0.1905$  or $19.05\%$    -  probability that the coin from the cashier that weighs more than 25 grams is counterfeit.

Comment: A looks good, B has an 0.8 that should not be there (you already know the coin is genuine, right?), C seems to be the same question as A but your answer is multiplying the chances that a coin could be above 25g (what could that even mean, a coin that is both genuine and counterfeit?), D starts with the wrong P...

Comment: Thanks for your help.